# Is it viable to use a moderate lengthy operation to run inside a .NET Web Api method

Tags: c#, .net, api, task

I red an excellent article about asynchronous tasks inside a Web API method, see link:

http://blog.tonysneed.com/2013/03/22/async-services-asp-net-web-api-entity-framework-6

Now for my solution (Framework 4.0) I have a third party tool which can transform an URL into an image. I like to use this inside a Web Api method. Example pseudo code:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SaveSomething(...)
{
   SaveSomethingToDatabase(...);

   var image = ThirdPartyTool(someUrl);
   image.Save("someFullName");
}
```

Because the third party tool takes some time (3 to 6 seconds on average, the Url called loads a Google Maps layer) I like to know if I should embed this inside a Task (like the article describes, but then the third party tool should have some async support which it hasn't) or is Web Api reliable enough to handle this kind of scenario's (regarding multiple repeated requests)?

A better way would be of course to create a windows service dedicated in creating images. But then I need to create a lot of extra stuff (a reliable image queue, a windows service an installer ect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, ASP.NET 4.0 does not support `async` and `await`. Full stop. If you install Microsoft.Bcl.Async, you can get it to *compile*, but the [behavior at runtime is **undefined**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx). End of story, sorry.

---

But even if it was possible (e.g., after upgrading to ASP.NET 4.5), you still wouldn't want to do this. You should absolutely not wrap this in a `Task`.

Consider the current synchronous behavior:

- Request comes in; ASP.NET takes a thread from its thread pool and assigns it to the request.
- Request is processed synchronously. Part of the time (within the `ThirdPartyTool` method), the request thread is blocked and idle.

This is not ideal, because you do have a request thread that is blocked not doing anything useful. However, ASP.NET is designed to handle this scenario gracefully, since it is (today) quite common.

Now, let's wrap it in a `Task`. Since the third-party tool is fully synchronous, the only option we really have is `Task.Run` or an equivalent:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SaveSomething(...)
{
  SaveSomethingToDatabase(...);

  var image = await Task.Run(() => ThirdPartyTool(someUrl));
  image.Save("someFullName");
}
```

Now, consider how this asynchronous request is handled:

- Request comes in; ASP.NET takes a thread `A` from its thread pool and assigns it to the request.
- When the handler hits `Task.Run`, it queues `ThirdPartyTool` to the thread pool. This takes *another* thread `B` from ASP.NET's thread pool and starts executing the code.
- The handler `await`s the task returned from `Task.Run`. This frees up the request thread `A`, allowing it to return to the ASP.NET thread pool.
- When the second thread `B` completes `ThirdPartyTool`, it notifies the handler that its task is complete. The handler then executes `Save` (as an optimization, the remainder of the handler is actually executed on thread `B` instead of pulling another thread from the thread pool, but that's an implementation detail).

If you think about it, it's definitely a performance pessimization. You're doing the same amount of work but also doing at least one extra context switch and messing with the ASP.NET thread pool heuristics twice by unexpectedly taking a task and then unexpectedly returning it later.

For this reason, it's a good guideline to *avoid `Task.Run` in ASP.NET*.

Wrapping code in `Task.Run` is what I call "fake asynchronous" - it *acts* asynchronous and *looks* asynchronous but underneath it's just queueing work to a thread pool thread.

Now, if you have a *truly* asynchronous operation, it's a different story. Let's say that the third party upgrades its tool with asynchronous support, and they do it right. Then your handler could look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SaveSomething(...)
{
  SaveSomethingToDatabase(...);

  var image = await ThirdPartyToolAsync(someUrl);
  image.Save("someFullName");
}
```

And this time the asynchronous request is handled completely differently:

- Request comes in; ASP.NET takes a thread from its thread pool and assigns it to the request.
- `ThirdPartyToolAsync` starts an asynchronous web request to Google (or whatever).
- The handler `await`s the task returned from `ThirdPartyToolAsync`. This frees up the request thread, allowing it to return to the ASP.NET thread pool.
- There are now no threads executing this request. At all.
- Later, the web request (or whatever) completes, and ASP.NET takes a thread from its thread pool to continue the handler.
- That thread finishes `ThirdPartyToolAsync` and proceeds to finish `SaveSomething`.

It's only with truly asynchronous methods like this that you get any benefit from `async` on ASP.NET, because you're *reducing* the pressure on the thread pool. Fake asynchronous methods *increase* the pressure, providing negative benefit.

Comment: I tested it and you are right, embedding it inside a Task this way is fake-asynchronous processing. Thank you for your thorough explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for requests that take a long time you should use `async Task<T>` and `await` where T is the type of data you're looking to return.

Blocking a main thread while waiting for an external tool operation to finish is unacceptable for performance. As specified in your linked article, the web API will end up spawning threads if written in synchronous form.

As it happens, .NET is relatively lenient about this - other APIs such as Android 4.4 actively throw exceptions when attempting to perform certain operations on the main thread (e.g. HTTP requests). In that case, the only way (or at least the neatest way) to perform such operations is via use of an Android `AsyncTask`.

Comment: "The service will be unable to handle any other requests until the operation finishes." - That doesn't sound right, the web service is not single threaded. If it was, running the actual work in a different thread would not free up the main thread as it would still be waiting.

Comment: That's true. I've simply edited that out, since the real issue here is covered in the linked blog anyway. (Which does somewhat defeat the point of the question)

Comment: I was unsure because my third party tool is not 'async' aware and the blog examples have code embedded inside a task which have async support. So my conclusion was for my situation it would make no sense to use a Task construction.